# Using CASE alongside IF & AND

Tags: formula-field

2 questions in a couple of hours, I'm on a roll.

I have two formula fields which drive a traffic light status on my opportunities. I'm trying to change the criteria that drives them to be a bit more exansive that what it is currently but I'm struggling to get the syntax right, if it's even possible.

Current formula

```
IF( Probability < 0.26, "Red",
IF( Probability > 0.25 && Probability <=0.75, "Amber", "Green"))
```

I want to change if to the below but it's not working.

```
IF(AND( Competitors_Known__c="Competetive",Probability<0.31),"Purple",
IF(AND( Competitors_Known__c="Unknown",Probability<0.31),"Purple",
IF(AND( Competitors_Known__c="Non-Competetive",Probability<0.31),"Red",
IF(Probability>0.49,"Orange",
IF(Probability>0.69,"Amber",
IF(Probability>0.79,"Green",null))))))
```

I'm thinking that simple nested IFs along with AND just won't cut it so CASE will be required but I can't grasp how to build them together.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit, Mark. I couldn't find the formula tags.

Comment: Since it may be affecting your formula logic and should be corrected, the word "competitive" is spelled incorrectly in your field values.

Comment: Your nested-if syntax looks fine. What part of the logic isn't working? What type of field is `Competitors_Known__c`?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Not only was I spelling Competitve incorrectly, I was referencing the wrong field. Thanks for pointing out the obvious, MArk.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem may start here:

```
IF(Probability>0.49,"Orange",
```

I think you'll need

```
IF(AND(Probability>0.49,"Orange", Probability<=0.69 ),
```

Otherwise, probability of .75 and .82 will all evaluate to true on this line.  Likewise, the "Amber" line will need similar alteration.

Comment: Alternatively, the logic of Green, Amber, and Orange could be reversed, putting the largest first, if Probability is the only criteria which is critical.

Comment: The original statement works no problem, the issue is with the second one. I have to introduce the second criteria of Competitors_Known__c for two of the possible statuses. That's the bit I'm struggling with.

Comment: As you can probably tell, Stack Exchange is new to me, need to keep up with both comment threads